# how can i insert image in ckeditor when we click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have ck editor and add gap button.in the ckeditor's text area i added an image.when i click on "add gap" button the same image will again add in the text area of the ck editor.i tried a lot but can't.please help me

thanks&regaurd's
sindu

```
                                    <div class="control-group" align="left" style="float: left" onselect="selectText()">
                                        <textarea name="editor1" id="myTextarea"><p>bdfv<img src="img/gap-placeholder.png"/></p> </textarea>
                                    </div>

                                    <div style="float: left;margin-left: 5px">
                                        <input type="button"  value="Add Gap"  onclick="insertText();">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the insertHTML function for ckeditor.

```
var editor = var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance;
var data = '<img src="img/gap-placeholder.png"/>';
editor.insertHtml(data, 'unfiltered_html');
```